# Videojs private laravel storage + vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, video.js, laravel-storage

I am facing problem with accessing privately stored videos from my server via laravel,videojs and vuejs.

Here is my controller method:

```
 public function fetchPrivateVideo($video)
{

    $video_path = '/private/courses/episodes/' . $video . "/" . $video . '.m3u8';
    // $video_path = '/private/courses/episodes/' . $video . '.mp4';

    if (!Storage::disk('local')->exists($video_path)) {
        abort(404);
    } else {
        $local_path = config('filesystems.disks.local.root') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $video_path;

        return response()->file($local_path);
    }
}
```

Response from this methods is for example this:

## EXTM3U

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=100000

060204b9-a084-44bf-86f2-c1128dd6bcb9_100.m3u8

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=250000

060204b9-a084-44bf-86f2-c1128dd6bcb9_250.m3u8

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=500000

060204b9-a084-44bf-86f2-c1128dd6bcb9_500.m3u8

which is the same response of publicly stored videos when accessed.

I am having simple videojs player and custom vuejs component:

```
    export default {
  props: ["episode", "course", "author"],
  data() {
    return {
      videoLoaded: true,
      videoOptions: {
        autoplay: false,
        controls: true,

        sources: [
          {
            src: `/video/episode/${this.episode.path}/fetch`,
            type: "application/x-mpegURL"
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  components: {
    appComments,
    VideoPlayer
  }
};
```

Data from above components are then used in general video player components which looks like this.:

```
   <template>
  <div>
    <video
      ref="videoPlayer"
      class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered"
      controls
      preload="auto"
      width="640"
      height="268"
      data-setup='{"fluid": true}'
    ></video>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import videojs from "video.js";

export default {
  name: "VideoPlayer",
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {};
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      player: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.player = videojs(
      this.$refs.videoPlayer,
      this.options
      //   function onPlayerReady() {
      //     console.log("onPlayerReady", this);
      //   }
    );
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.dispose();
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style src="video.js/dist/video-js.min.css"></style>
```

The problem is that the video is not getting loaded and does not start it just creates many requests trying to fetch the video unsuccessfully and players stays dead at just a simple spinning loading wheel.

Could anyone advise me how to handle this issue? I need some videos to be accessed privately after some checks done in middleware. Note that this is SPA built in laravel and vue.js

Answer (score 1):

I found out very interesting fact. I had to change my controller method because those many requests that it created were trying to fetch next part of video based on the m3u8 playlist file, but could not because the URL was wrong and files were not getting found. Note that URL is getting changed but each following part of the video. Like this:

Initial video fetch:
Request URL: localhost:800/video/episode/fetch/060204b9-a084-44bf-86f2-c1128dd6bcb9

Following URLs:
Request URL: localhost:800/video/episode/fetch/060204b9-a084-44bf-86f2-c1128dd6bcb9_500.m3u8

Request URL: localhost:800/video/episode/fetch/060204b9-a084-44bf-86f2-c1128dd6bcb9_500_00000.ts

etc.

This is how I edited the controller method:

```
    public function fetchPrivateVideo($video)
{
    $arr = explode("_", $video, 2);
    $first = $arr[0];

    $contains = \Str::contains($video, ['.m3u8', 'ts']);

    if ($contains) {
        $video_path = '/private/courses/episodes/' . $first . "/" . $video;
    } else {
        $video_path = '/private/courses/episodes/' . $first . "/" . $video . '.m3u8';
    }

    if (!Storage::disk('local')->exists($video_path)) {
        abort(404);
    } else {
        $local_path = config('filesystems.disks.local.root') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $video_path;

        return response()->file($local_path);
}
```

Basically I am modifying the path because once the initial part of video is fetched you need to modify the url so that it fetches the next parts.

Also be very careful when specifying the route for fetching video and next parts. You want something that ends with parameters and does not have any fixed words between.

Incorrect:
Route::get('/video/episode/{video}/fetch', 'VideoController@fetchPrivateVideo');

Correct:
Route::get('/video/episode/fetch/{video}', 'VideoController@fetchPrivateVideo');

Comment: Thank you for providing this. is your code still working?